# Outlet looses power only after two breakers are switched off.

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, circuit-breaker

I have some track lights that run in my upstairs bedroom. A while ago they stopped working, I could flip the switch but there was no light. So I get around to doing some investigating and grab my non-contact meter and there is definitely voltage to each track. Next I take out the multi-meter to test the AC voltage. I was getting 84v AC which is too low, so I am thinking that maybe I have a bad neutral connection or something.

I head down to the basement to start flipping the breakers. I didn't have my entire house mapped at the time so I started turning off one breaker at a time and then running back upstairs to check the voltage with the non-contact meter.  Well sure enough I tried them all and never got the power disconnected from the tracks.  I then proceeded to turn of one whole side of the breaker box, go and check the voltage, and there is no voltage at the track. I figured I must have made a mistake when checking the 40 individually and proceed to turn the breakers on two at a time so I don't have to run up and down stairs so often. Finally I get power back to the tracks, I go downstairs and turn one of the two breakers off, and find that I still have voltage to the track. I think I have isolated the correct breaker until I turn the isolated one off and the one next to it on. I check the tracks again, and I still have voltage to them.

I can only remove the power if both breakers are closed. Did the two circuits accidentally get wired together? Can anyone else think what the cause of this might be?

Comment: Sure sounds like it...maybe you can post some photos of the situation?

Comment: "*I can only remove the power if both breakers are closed.*"  Do you mean when both breakers are *open*?  When a breaker is in the **OFF** position, the contacts inside are **open**. Sorry to nip pick, but it's important to know if the breakers are *on* or *off*.

Comment: Non-contact meters are notorious for telling you there's voltage present when there is none. You should re-test with a contact meter or test load.